# Is there an Euler diagram of SQL Server 'sys' tables?

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

I am trying to wrap my head around which tables to include in queries on the sys tables because it sounds like some objects might appear in multiple places according to the summary descriptions that can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

e.g. tables should exist (in some form) in sys.columns, sys.objects, sys.tables

Comment: I normally just query information_schema.columns or the equivalent base dmv to search for column_name like '%table%' to match your example.

Comment: yeah but that doesn't really help if you're also searching inside procs

Comment: system procs or your own ? have you looked at the Object_Definition function ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: & you should check out this link too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What *information* are you actually trying to obtain from the system catalog views?